"Symbolic powers" of exterior differential systems
Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, $\mathscr I\subseteq\Omega(M)$ an exterior differential system (i.e. a homogeneous differential ideal in the exterior algebra). We can consider the ordinary ideal powers $$ \mathscr I^k=\left\{\omega\in\Omega(M): \omega=\sum_i\theta_{1,i}\wedge\dots\wedge\theta_{k,i},\quad,\theta_{a,i}\in\mathscr I\right\}. $$
We can also consider the following recursive definition by $\mathscr I^{(1)}:=\mathscr I$ and $$ \mathscr I^{(k)}=\left\{\omega\in\mathscr I^{(k-1)}: X\rfloor\omega\in\mathscr I^{(k-1)},\forall X\in\mathfrak D(M)\right\},\quad k>1 $$ i.e. $\mathscr I^{(k)}$ consists of those elements which belong to $\mathscr I$ when contracted with any $l$ ($0\le l\le k-1 $) vector fields.
Clearly, $\mathscr I^k\subseteq\mathscr I^{(k)}$.
Do the ideals $\mathscr I^{(k)}$ have a name? Due to similarities of symbolic powers of (prime, I think) polynomial ideals, I usually call $\mathscr I^{(k)}$ the $k$th symbolic power of $\mathscr I$, but this does not seem to be a standard name.
The main question I have is do we have any useful criteria for determining when $\mathscr I^{(k)}=\mathscr I^k$? When $\mathscr I$ is an integrable Pfaffian ideal (i.e. generated by linear forms locally of finite rank), we have this equivalence, but not in general, I think.
